# polars df.sum(axis=1) for Expressions (and other functions, maybe median?)

Tags: python-polars

I'm trying to find a polaric way of aggregating data per row. It's not strictly about `.sum` function, it's about all aggregations where `axis` makes sense.
Take a look at these `pandas` examples:

`df[df.sum(axis=1) > 5]`

`df.assign(median=df.median(axis=1))`

`df[df.rolling(3, axis=1).mean() > 0]`

However, with `polars`, problems start really quick:

`df.filter(df.sum(axis=1)>5)`

`df.with_column(df.mean(axis=1).alias('mean'))` - cant do median

`df...` - cant do rolling, rank and anything more complex.

I saw the page where `polars` authors suggest doing everything by hand with `fold`s, but there are cases where logic doesn't fit into one input and one accumulator variable (i.e. simple median)

Moreover, this approach seems to not work at all when using `Expr`essions, i.e. `pl.all().sum(axis=1)` is not valid since for some reason `axis` argument is absent.

So the question is: how to deal with these situations? I hope to have the full `polars` api at my fingertips, instead of some suboptimal solutions i can come up with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

#### Row-wise computations:

[You can create a list and access the `.arr` namespace for row wise computations.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/list_context.html#row-wise-computations)

[@ritchie46's answer regarding `rank(axis=1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71951543) is also useful reading.

[`.arr.eval()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.arr.eval.html#polars.Expr.arr.eval) can be used for more complex computations.

```
df = pl.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 3], [1, 8, 9]])
(df.with_column(pl.concat_list(pl.all()).alias("row"))
   .with_columns([
      pl.col("row").arr.sum().alias("sum"),
      pl.col("row").arr.mean().alias("mean"),
      pl.col("row").arr.eval(pl.all().median(), parallel=True).alias("median"),
      pl.col("row").arr.eval(pl.all().rank(),   parallel=True).alias("rank"),
   ])
)
shape: (3, 8)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┬─────┬──────┬───────────┬─────────────────┐
│ column_0 | column_1 | column_2 | row       | sum | mean | median    | rank            │
│ ---      | ---      | ---      | ---       | --- | ---  | ---       | ---             │
│ i64      | i64      | i64      | list[i64] | i64 | f64  | list[f64] | list[f32]       │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═════╪══════╪═══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1        | 4        | 1        | [1, 4, 1] | 6   | 2.0  | [1.0]     | [1.5, 3.0, 1.5] │
├──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┼─────┼──────┼───────────┼─────────────────┤
│ 2        | 5        | 8        | [2, 5, 8] | 15  | 5.0  | [5.0]     | [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] │
├──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┼─────┼──────┼───────────┼─────────────────┤
│ 3        | 3        | 9        | [3, 3, 9] | 15  | 5.0  | [3.0]     | [1.5, 1.5, 3.0] │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┴─────┴──────┴───────────┴─────────────────┘
```

---

#### [`pl.sum()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.sum.html#polars.sum)

Can be given a list of columns.

```
>>> df.select(pl.sum(pl.all()))
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ sum │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 6   │
├─────┤
│ 15  │
├─────┤
│ 15  │
└─────┘
```

---

#### [`.rolling_mean()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_mean.html#polars-expr-rolling-mean)

Can be accessed inside `.arr.eval()`

```
pdf = df.to_pandas()
pdf[pdf.rolling(2, axis=1).mean() > 3]
   column_0  column_1  column_2
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       5.0       8.0
2       NaN       NaN       9.0
```

```
(df.with_column(pl.concat_list(pl.all()).alias("row"))
   .with_column(
      pl.col("row").arr.eval(
         pl.when(pl.all().rolling_mean(2) > 3)
           .then(pl.all()), 
         parallel=True)
      .alias("rolling[mean] > 3"))
)
shape: (3, 5)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┬────────────────────┐
│ column_0 | column_1 | column_2 | row       | rolling[mean] > 3  │
│ ---      | ---      | ---      | ---       | ---                │
│ i64      | i64      | i64      | list[i64] | list[i64]          │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1        | 4        | 1        | [1, 4, 1] | [null, null, null] │
├──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┼────────────────────┤
│ 2        | 5        | 8        | [2, 5, 8] | [null, 5, 8]       │
├──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┼────────────────────┤
│ 3        | 3        | 9        | [3, 3, 9] | [null, null, 9]    │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┴────────────────────┘
```

If you want to "expand" the lists into columns:

1. Turn the list into a struct with `.arr.to_struct()`
2. [`.unnest()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) the struct.
3. Rename the columns (if needed)

```
(df.with_column(pl.concat_list(pl.all()).alias("row"))
   .select(
      pl.col("row").arr.eval(
         pl.when(pl.all().rolling_mean(2) > 3)
           .then(pl.all()),
         parallel=True)
      .arr.to_struct()
      .alias("rolling[mean]"))
   .unnest("rolling[mean]")
)
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ field_0 | field_1 | field_2 │
│ ---     | ---     | ---     │
│ i64     | i64     | i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ null    | null    | null    │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ null    | 5       | 8       │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ null    | null    | 9       │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

---

#### `.transpose()`

You could always transpose the dataframe to switch the axis and use the *"regular"* api.

```
(df.transpose()
   .select(
      pl.when(pl.all().rolling_mean(2) > 3)
        .then(pl.all())
        .keep_name())
   .transpose())
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 | column_1 | column_2 │
│ ---      | ---      | ---      │
│ i64      | i64      | i64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ null     | null     | null     │
├──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ null     | 5        | 8        │
├──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ null     | null     | 9        │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer! but tell me, is it a good idea (performance-wise) to have all those lists? maybe I should explode them and `.groupby.agg()`? Or maybe `transpose` is going to be a better option? Im going to test all the cases myself, but is there something you could recommend as a rule of thumb ?